# Why are for..in faster than for loops when looping through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, for-loop

I have been wonder where a `for` loop or a `for..in` loop would be farther on an array.

I have tested this using [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/forloops-methodstest).

My `For` Loop had `16,676,377 op/s`
while the `for..in` only had `519,853 op/s`

So why is:

```
var a = ["hi", "hi2", "bye", "bye2"];

for (var i in a) {
  return a[i];
}
```

Slower compared to:

```
var a = ["hi", "hi2", "bye", "bye2"];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  return a[i];
}
```

Comment: They do different things (and are implemented differently). So .. what's the question?

Comment: @pst, OP doesn't understand what they do differently.

Comment: Actually your return statements kind of breaks up everything

Comment: Incrementing a counter to get the next property to resolve is probably more efficient than searching the object and it's `[[Prototype]]` chain for enumerable properties that must then be resolved.

Comment: Ha, I totally forgot that return is going to break up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for your question is simple: for in loop was not created to deal with arrays and does additional things as well and should not be used.

The main purpose of the for-in statement is to iterate thought object's properties, not through the array. This statement will also go into the array prototype chain, iteration through inherited properties and I think you do not need this or even do not know about this.

Another funny thing that you even do not know in what order it will be iterated.

So the main thing to remember - do not use for in with arrays. Only with objects.

P.S as RobG correctly added:

> A for loop will search for properties on the [[Prototype]] chain too if they aren't found on the array. E.g. a for loop over [0,,2] will search for 1 all the way to Object.prototype[[Prototype]]

Comment: A for loop will search for properties on the `[[Prototype]]` chain too if they aren't found on the array. E.g. a for loop over `[0,,2]` will search for `1` all the way to `Object.prototype[[Prototype]]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

1. your `return` in the loop's body causes the loop to abort after the first iteration, your tests are useless
2. `for..in` loops over an object's properties, an array's elements are *not its only properties*! were you to add a property, such as `a.foo = true`; that would be included in iterating with `for..in` but not in `for`.

Please don't use `for..in` to loop arrays. Not. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the JavaScript engine implementation. Because JavaScript is dynamically typed, the interpreter has to do some work to establish the type of a given variable. I suspect there are optimisations in the engine for the classic integer iterator for loop that aren't available when using for...in.

**EDIT:**

for..in iterates through the enumerable properties of a variable, so var i is assigned the value of each string in your array on each loop.

Comment: Silly me - how did I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

To explain why a `for` loop is faster than a `for in` loop is basically understand the underlying data structures used to store the data in memory.
Looping through an indexed based array is naturally faster because of the way an array is stored in memory. It's just a location in memory and the items in the array are stored in consecutive locations, aka. in order and next to each other. Generally it's fast to retrieve elements in consecutive order because you don't have to spend time to find it, you just know the next item is always the next location beside it. And because it knows the `array.length` and can determine which chunks of memory has been portioned off for the array.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to believe that the value of a[2] will necessarily be stored adjacent to a[3], or that such storage is necessarily faster than other storage options. More likely the difference in performance is simply an implementation choice to optimise for loops and not worry so much about for..in loops since for loops are used much more often.

Comment: I don't know exactly how they implemented the JavaScript engines so I can't say for certain... but generally speaking, arrays are fast because of the way they're stored/accessed in memory.